# How to check for special characters? (Google Chrome DevTools)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, character-encoding, google-chrome-devtools

When I execute

```
""
```

(String.fromCharCode(7))

in Google Chrome's console it turns to

```
"�"
```

but returns

```
""
```

(String.fromCharCode(7))

Is there a way to check if it will turn to "�"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing what happens when you execute a command in google chrome's devtools 
[(You can do that by undocking devtools into separate window and pressing CTRL+SHIFT+J again)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95D9o.png)

I found this line of code:

[image: Line of code]

In that window `String.prototype` had `replaceControlCharacters` function:

[image: ReplaceControlCharacters function]

So to check if a single character string would turn to "�" you could use this:

```
function isSpecialCharacter(c){
    return /[\u0000-\u0008\u000b\u000c\u000e-\u001f\u0080-\u009f]/g.test(c);
}

console.log(isSpecialCharacter(String.fromCharCode(7))) // true
console.log(isSpecialCharacter("t")) // false
```